# Why do both Olivia and Peter remember so little from their childhood?

Tags: fringe

I just watched S3E15, "Subject 13", in which it is revealed that Peter and Olivia

> have met before, and Walter tried to train Olivia to cross over, *specifically* to bring Peter back to his universe.
>  Also, Olivia confided in Walter when her stepfather abused her, and he seemed to be the first one to stand up for her. Peter went looking for her when she ran away.

These are all very important events in their young lives. Why does neither remember anything of that? They must have been at least 6 years old at the time<sup>‡</sup>, more likely 8.

Olivia can't have been older than 9, since in S1E6 *The Cure*, she tells Peter how she shot (but did not kill) her stepfather when she was 9, because he was abusing her mother.

People have memories from much earlier in life. Is it explained why neither remembers any of this?

---

‡

> Peter died over here when he was 6 or 7 (his grave stone read "1978 - 1985"), so Peter from over there must have been at least that age.

Comment: Well, I know I have very few memories from that young...

Comment: I have memories from before we moved, at three and a half. I have more than enough memories from when I was six, and Olivia and Peter as portrayed in that episode were more like eight or so. (How old was Peter when he crossed over?)

Comment: @SQB: Good for you I guess but most people don't.

Comment: @SQB I also have a handful of memories from around 3 years old.  It's not like a solid line of forgetting - only random things here and there I still remember, is what I meant to say, and the older it is, the more likely to be forgotten

Comment: Slightly more directly comparable, I have a facebook friend I have no memories of, although her face is vaguely familiar.  However, she uploaded pictures from a birthday party from when we were ~6 or 7 years years old that I'm in.  Memory is not consistent  =(

Comment: Most adults remember relatively little from their childhoods before age 7, but some retain vivid memories. According to the Wiki on _Childhood Memory_, recall is improved if the mother reminisces with the child; it also improves as the child learns more words. (Practice makes perfect?) Traumatic events such as child abuse can interfere with the accuracy of memory. I discussed recall with one young man who claimed to have very few memories of his life before age 11, when his parents were divorced. In my 60s, I have a few memories that can be dated to when I was two and a half years old.

Answer (score 1):

Jacksonville Trials were ran between 1981 and 1983 (**Fringe Wikia**). So this would be original Peter.

**UPDATE: Chastened by SQB need to add that obviously episode  is set in 1986 and it's the other Peter, so inconsistence is possible**

Olivia doesn't remember due to trauma (you never remember the moment of any more serious incident), repressed memory (Jacksonville was not fun) and some meds/hypnosis stuff that Nick mentions: "They meant for us to forget".

Comment: That makes no sense, since the episode makes it quite clear that it's the other Peter. So perhaps it's after the initial trials. Where did you get that date for the Jacksonville Trials?

Comment: Fringepedia and other re-sources. Admittedly, cursory read shows no initial source for that is provided. My memory is foggy on that, but I'm re-watching the show so will keep my eye and ear sharp.
I also had an impression about it being the other Peter, however the dates do not match.
My bet is on scripting issues.

Comment: Correction: Fringe Wikia.
Can I ask why down vote? I can't comment yet, so only way to contribute is to answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit harsh perhaps, especially to a new user. (Hello and welcome, please check the [help] and take the [tour]; enjoy your stay). It was mainly because of the unfounded assumption that it must've been the original Peter while the episode (and my question) make clear it's not, and the unlikely and unsourced dates for the Jacksonville Trials. Unfortunately, I cannot reverse the vote unless the question is edited.

Answer (score 1):

There are several mentions, especially in S1 & S2, that Walter experimented on Peter (probably Red Peter), with electric shocks.  There are a couple of plausible explanations:
1) Walter wanted Peter to forget childhood events (like crossing dimensions), and 2) Somehow Walter knew that Peter would ultimately end up in The Machine, and needed to withstand higher voltage than the 'average' person (although this one is a little shaky).

That explains Peter's lack of memory.  For Olivia... perhaps the drugs and the experiments?  Perhaps she blocked them out?  I don't think anything was specifically cited.